# WebServiceexception "No Content-type in the header" when trying to consume JBoss hosted webservice with a console application

Tags: eclipse, jbossws

I have a small assignment where I have to consume a webservice hosted with JBoss using a console application.

I have 2 projects in the same workspace, The DynamicWebApplication that I used as a webservice that is hosted using JBoss and a console application to access it. The console application also has the java files generated with wsimport

I am using the Eclipse IDE and whilst searching through the internet I found that I needed to copy the libraries found in JBOSS_HOME/common/lib to JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed but I still have the issue. Any ideas on why this is occurring?

PS. These are the libraries that I copied:

```
 jbossws-native-jaxrpc.jar
 jbossws-native-jaxws.jar
 jbossws-native-jaxws-ext.jar
 jbossws-native-saaj.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution the the problem. Apparently I had to add the following code in the vm arguements:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/path-to/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/endorsed
```